# Elasticsearch: Filter on array field that is subset of another array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in elasticsearch that one of their fields is an array field. i.e.

```
document = {
        id : ###,
        name: 'SSSSS',
        items : ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC'] 
       }
```

I want to get all the documents that their `items` field is a subset of some input array.

for example, if I filter on

```
['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC', 'itemD', 'itemE']
```

I'll get the document above because all of the items in `document.items` are in the input array.

But if I filter on:

```
['itemA', 'itemB','itemD', 'itemE']
```

Then I won't get the document above, becuase the document has `itemC` and the input array doesn't.

Is there a way to perform this using the Query DSL?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the query you're using and can you share the mapping of the `items` field?

Comment: You can do this with a [script filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), but it's ugly and probably inefficient. I don't know of a way to do set inclusion like this without hacking it.

Comment: Hi there, did you find an answer to your question?